# How to say "some" in French, as in "Some lady asked you this..." or "He's asking for some book you own"

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

How would you say some in French? As in "Some lady asked you...". Would you say

> Une dame quelconque vous a demandé

Answer (score 7):

Lorsque *some* concerne une seule personne on le traduit par *un* ou *une*, et le contexte de la phrase permettra de préciser la spécificité de cette personne.

> Une femme<sup>1</sup> vous a demandé...

Pour la seconde partie de la question,  “He's asking for some book you own” :

> Il demande un de vos livres.

---

<sup>1 - *Cf. : le choix de [traduire lady en femme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19895/dans-quel-contexte-le-mot-dame-est-il-utilis%C3%A9).*</sup>

Comment: 1) Je pense que la traduction de *lady* dans cette phrase serait légèrement mieux rendue par "dame" que par "femme" (qui aurait correspondu à *woman*). Il peut en français comme en anglais s'agir d'un terme d'adresse respectueux sans forcément de connotation de classe sociale. Par exemple un patron de café dira à sa serveuse: "La dame de la 17 a commandé un jambon-beurre", pas "la femme".

Comment: 2) "Une femme quelconque" signifie *some random woman*. Il y a l'accent sur le fait qu'il s'agit vraiment de quelqu'un qui était là par pur hasard voire par erreur

Comment: @qoba -- J'ai complété ma réponse en tenant compte de vos commentaires

Comment: J'ai supprimé le hors sujet. Je te propose de rependre le contenu dans une réponse à la question « Dans quel contexte le mot dame est-il utilisé ? » (qui peut être posée sur le site).

Answer (score 0):

On peut aussi dire:

> Quelque femme vous a demandé.

Mais cela n'est pas à utiliser en dehors d'un cadre littéraire.

Answer (score 0):

A commentary on informal usage, in complement of the other answers:

In spoken French, we strongly avoid having indefinite referents, or referents that are new to the conversation(1), in the subject position.

Instead, we use a clause with the verb *y avoir* (usually translated as "there is", but more really meaning "there exists" hence the term "existential cleft" describing this structure in the literature) to introduce the new information, and have the main verb in a subordinate sentence with *qui* as the subject.

In a text or when speaking, what you'll have most of the time is thus:

> **Y'a** une dame **qui** t'a demandé

Which keeps the new information (une dame) in the more suitable role of an object.

---

(1) These two categories tend to overlap each other of course.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer... I don't think "y'a XX qui..." is more used than the indefinite form. And it's certainly not used that much in written text. I also don't agree that in this form "une dame" is an object : "Il y a des hommes qui t'ont demandé", the verb is plural, according to the subject, "des hommes". Now I may have misunderstood what you meant...

Comment: @LaurentS. "in a text" = in a text message, dans un SMS, dans un texto, (or say in a tweet) not in a written formal document. In your sentence, "des hommes" is the syntactic object of "il y a" and the semantic subject of "t'ont" but the syntactic subject of the second verb is "qui". As for frequency of use of the cleft vs. the canonical subject position, I can't find any corpus study online about it, just absolute frequencies of the cleft in different medium (https://www.arts.kuleuven.be/ling/presentationalclefts/2015_Lahousse_Karssenberg_presentation_Paris, p. 10).

Comment: Nevertheless, I maintain that an indefinite NP is relatively infelicitous in subject position in Spoken French in an All-Focus context (i.e. as a plausible answer to “Qu’est-ce qui se passe ?”), as is its subject doubled equivalent (“Une femme, elle t’a demandé…”). Think about the number of dumb jokes or street stories that begin with “Y’a un mec, il…”. That's the usual way to form that kind of sentence.

Comment: I don't agree at all. Thinking of jokes : "Un juif, un arabe et un catholique entrent dans un bar", "un mec attend au feu", etc... ". I find "il y a" very emphatic for such texts. I would also never use such extra characters in a SMS or a tweet, just because it's faster to not use extra characters. Thanks anyway for the grammatical correction on subject/object, on this I totally agree.