# Dans quel contexte le mot dame est-il utilisé ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

J'aurais tendance à traduire *lady* et *woman* par *femme*, en partant du principe qu'en France toutes les *femmes* sont des *ladies* (peut-être l'origine du 'glamour' ?), les *femelles* sont animales, les *dames* des bourgeoises, parfois des aristocrates.

Si l'on peut désigner la *femme* dont on parle, on peut alors employer le mot *dame* comme marque de respect, de non familiarité :

> Cette *dame* vous a demandé...

Alors que :

> Cette *femme* vous a demandé...

est tout aussi correct et respectueux ; il ne marque pas de distance, et sera plus naturellement employé.

On emploie aussi *dame* lorsqu'on s'adresse à une *personne* à qui l'on doit le respect et que l'on désigne une personne dont on ne connaît pas le nom :

> Mr le professeur, une *dame* vous a demandé...

... évidemment ce sera "Votre femme vous a demandé..." (plutôt que votre *épouse*, qui est un terme juridique que l'on n'emploie pas dans le langage courant) si l'on connaît cette dernière.

---

Y a-t-il d'autres contextes pour lesquels l'emploi de *femme* et de *dame* ne sont pas vraiment interchangeables ?

Est-ce que cette sorte de synonyme est spécifique à la traduction d'un contexte de relations sociales ?

Comment: "La Dame du Lac" n'est pas interchangeable :o

Comment: @SimonDéchamps -- Je pense surtout aux contextes de traductions. Pourquoi le terme galant de l'ancien temps, *dame*, est devenu *femme* de nos jours ? Le caractère noble de *dame* s'est transféré  au mot *femme* (citoyenne), mais quelles qualités spécifiques restent rattachées au mot *dame* ?

Comment: oui je plaisantais, je ne saurai pas répondre à cette question.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre "toutes les femmes sont des *ladies*". À quoi vous référez-vous là ? Y a-t-il un contexte de traduction dans lequel on utiliserait femme de préférence à dame pour traduire *lady*?

Comment: @qoba -- Depuis la révolution, il n'y a plus de différence entre les femmes issues de la noblesse et celles du peuple. Certains noms ont une particule, mais cela ne leur confère aucun droit particulier. De ce fait, toutes les femmes ont la possibilité d'avoir les attributs de l'ancienne noblesse, en particulier pour ce qui concerne leur rang dans le monde.

Comment: OK je comprends ce contexte culturel. Il signifie qu'il n'y a pas en France de différence légale entre les femmes et que le titre officiel de Dame n'a pas plus cours que celui de "Monseigneur". Mais vous posez une question de linguistique ; la valeur distincte des deux termes n'a pas été effacée par un changement légal. Je ne vois toujours pas d'exemple où l'anglais *lady* se traduirait mieux par *femme* que par *dame*. Auriez-vous un tel exemple à proposer ?

Comment: @qoba -- C'est plutôt que le terme lady "C'est une lady" est tombé dans l'usage courant. J'ai rajouté 3 § dans ma question qui répondront peut-être à votre interrogation.

Comment: J'utilise le mot "épouse" dans le langage courant, pour ma part.

Comment: @KPM - Je ne l'ai entendu dit que par des couples mariés, plus souvent dans un contexte religieux que civil, ou dans des situation ou le langage soutenu était de rigueur ; mais cela devient de plus en plus rare que cela arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ne peut pas remplacer "femme" par dame quand:

- on parle de *femme* au sens d'*épouse* SAUF dans certains contextes aristocratiques particuliers (notamment quand on est un domestique et qu'on ne sait pas si il s'agit vraiment d'une épouse)
- dans l'expression "une recette de bonne femme", qui devrait étymologiquement se dire "une recette de bonne fame", même racine que "fameux".
- quand on ne parle pas d'une personne spécifique, mais de femmes en général, ou juste d'un aspect féminin: "il a des mains de femme", "les femmes sont toutes des hystériques", "j'en boirais cinq à six bouteilles, une femme sur les genoux".

On ne peut pas remplacer "dame" par "femme" quand:

- On évoque un titre: "la première dame de France", "la Dame du Lac"
- on fait référence aux pions, ou à la figure du jeu de cartes (ou aux interstices neutres du jeu de go)
- on utilise l'interjection vieillote: "dame!"
- on parle d'une personne qu'on considère comme d'un rang supérieur (à cause de son âge ou de sa catégorie sociale): "une dame de la haute société", "dis bonjour à la dame !" (utilisé pour apprendre la politesse à un enfant), "ces dames et ces messieurs sont-ils à leur aise ?"
- dans l'expression "gente dame".

Comment: Une recette de bonne fame :-) Bien joué, vous m'avez appris quelque chose

Answer (score 3):

Le mot dame est beaucoup utilisé dans les jeux de manière non interchangeable avec femme: aux échecs, dans les jeux de cartes et bien sûr au jeu de dame.

Un cas où le mot "dame" revêt toute sa noblesse (pas nécessairement dans le sens aristocratique) est :

> une grande dame

alors qu'avec "une grande femme" on pensera à la taille.

Quand "lady" est accompagné d'un adjectif ou d'un complément du nom, on le traduit souvent par "dame"

> The first lady ( La première dame, femme du Président)
>
> The Iron Lady ( La Dame de Fer, surnom de M. Thatcher)

Comment: Peut-être parce que pour les échecs il y a un roi, une reine, les (nobles) dames de la cour n'avaient droit qu'à un jeu de pions :) - En effet, dans les jeux de cartes *dame* est synonyme de *reine*, elle indique un titre.

Comment: Par contraste avec _une grande dame_, on peut parfois rencontrer l'expression familière _ma p'tite dame_.

Comment: @cl-r: la "reine" des échecs s'appelle en fait une *dame*. Coincidence ?

Answer (score 3):

Subjectivement parlant, je dirais que l'emploi des deux termes implique une subtile nuance dans la langue.

Par l'emploi de ***femme*** , on entend plus quelque chose d'indéfini et se rapportant de manière générale à un féminin.

Par l'emploi de ***dame***, on se rapporte plus généralement à un titre, ce qui invoque d'emblée une certaine ombre de respect supplémentaire par rapport à l'emploi de femme.

Dans l'exemple que vous employez :

> Cette *femme* vous a demandé...

J'aurais tendance à dire que vous devriez accéder à sa requête au nom du droit universel, des droits de l'homme etc.

Tandis que

> Cette *dame* vous a demandé

Ou mieux encore, plus fréquemment employé avec *dame*

> *La dame* vous a demandé

M'inspire plutôt l'invocation d'une déférence nécessairement due plutôt qu'un droit.